# code will not advance the row count, such that the data will print on subsequent rows

Tags: vb.net

I am trying (using VB) to copy 7 values from 1 location to another.
(copy from F115 to F134.)
(F115 is source of numbers; F134 is destination for numbers)
If there is data (any data) in F134 I want to advance the row by 1 and then print/copy.   I do not want to overwrite any lines of data.
So, if there is data in the first row (F134) then I want to move/advance the row count by 1 and then copy the values into row F135 - and so on.    It's possible that there could be 500 to 100 rows of numbers and I need to be able to view all of this data.
So far, this is the code I have: some works, but it does NOT advance the row count and continues to print into Cell F134. (oh yes, F124 is just a set of empty cells.)

Ok, this is my code;

```
Sub dbtest4()

Dim RowCounter As Integer
rowCounter = 1
Do Until rowCounter = rowCounter +1
         'trying to advance the row counter by 1 such that if there is data in F134, the line count will advance and the new data will print into the NEXT line. (which would be F135)

'the following code probably is unnecessary, but I'm trying anything...
'actually the following code works ok:  Range("F134").Resize(1,7).Value =  Range("F115").Resize(1,7).Value, but that's about it.

If Range ("F134") = 0 then
      Range("F134").Resize(1,7).Value = Range("F115").Resize(1,7).Value
         'trying to print data cells from F124 if there is no data in F134
Else
      Range("F134"),Resize(1,7).Value = Range("F124).Resize(1,7).Value
          'trying to print the zeros or blank numbers from F115 if F134 has data in it
      End if
Loop
Exit Do
End Sub
```

Thanks to anyone who may be able to offer some assistance.

Comment: `Do Until rowCounter = rowCounter +1` looks like you only want it to do one, except rowCounter is never incremented.  The stray `Exit Do` will prevent that from compiling

Answer (score 0):

So right now the exit condition for the Do While loop is that rowCounter has to increment by one. I can't see a reason why this should fail and that is why it is only happening once. Here is some psuedocode:

```
Do Until copiedVals = 7 'Or whatever exit value you want
    If row.Value.Exists() then
        'There is a value in this row, so increment the row count
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Else 
        'This row is empty and you can do your thing
        'rowCounter will have the current row value
        copiedVals = copiedVals + 1
    End If
End Loop
```